# Unable to start the C/C++ language server. IntelliSense features will be disabled

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, c++, extension, intellisense

After updating my **C++ intellisence** by **microsoft** I am getting the below error message while compiling with **ctrl+shift+b**

`Unable to start the C/C++ language server. IntelliSense features will be disabled. Error: Missing binary at c:\Users\Dev Parzival\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.1.0\bin\cpptools.exe`

Due this while pointing mouse over a function no information is shown.I know that I have not messed up with the configuration of `vscode` imediately after installing the update I am getting this error.

I have updated vscode.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same Issue !

Then i installed the previous older version 1.0.1 and no error now.

Comment: I tried to install older version but when I upgraded to latest version it started crashing and intelliscence stopeed working.

Comment: version 1.0.1 is `vscode version` or `c++ extension` by microsoft version?